# Make Spring ApplicationContext.close() stop immediately

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to enforce Spring's `ApplicationContext.close()` method to stop a service immediately? Whenever I call it (for sending the Shutdown Hook) the service still runs for at least 1 more minute. Or is there a better way for shutting down a Spring Boot service immediately? I want to prevent `System.exit`.

Comment: Closing the context does a controlled dispose of all beans. If it takes time to shut down, it generally means one or more of your beans have pre-destroy methods that take a long time (e.g. because they are waiting on something to finish). You need to find out where the time is spent, and try to see if you can fix that. For example, I once had an application that couldn't shut down quickly because the bean was in a timed wait on an empty queue, so the application stop was delayed until it woke up. We had to wake it up explicitly during the pre-destroy by adding a "poison pill" in the queue.

Comment: It can also mean your beans have non-daemon threads that take time to stop (similar as pre-destroy taking a while).

Answer (score 0):

Beans can be event listeners. Eg you can annotate a method on your bean with `@EventListener`. See [spring events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) for more options

Eg:

```java
@Component
public class MyService {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
   private ScheduledFuture future;

   public MyService(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
      this.executor = executor;
   }

   public synchronized void start() {
      if (future != null) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Already running");
      }
      Runnable task = () -> {
         // TODO implement
      };
      future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECOND);
   }

   public synchronized void stop() {
      if (future != null) {
         future.cancel(true); // mayInterruptIfRunning=true
         future = null;
      }
   }

   @EventListener
   public void contextStopped(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
      stop();
   }
}
```

See [Future.cancel(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-)

Comment: Hmmm, I'd like to shut the service down at the start-up in case the connection on an external server fails. So in best case my beans would not even got initialized. (I tried this inside the @Configuration bean for connecting to the server.)

Comment: See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to do any "work" in the constructors of your beans. So in theory you should always be able to construct the beans in your application context without errors.

It's best separate any startup "work" into it's own method. You can then have a single start/stop event handler for your whole application in a `@Configuration` which often makes it easier to control the ordering.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> refreshListener(
       Service1 service1,
       Service2 service2,
       Service3 service3
    ) {
       return event -> {
          // if any of these throw exception it will prevent your app from starting
          service1.start();
          service2.start();
          service3.start();
       };
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> closeListener(
       Service1 service1,
       Service2 service2,
       Service3 service3
    ) {
       return event -> {
          service3.stop();
          service2.stop();
          service1.stop();
       };
    }
}
```

See a real world example demonstrating this concept [here](https://github.com/uklance/wings/blob/master/wings-server/src/main/java/com/sample/webserver/configuration/WebServerConfiguration.java#L44-L94)